Android Resource Linking Failed: Unexpected <activity> Found in <manifest>
Body:
I'm currently developing a Flutter application, and I'm encountering an issue while building the app. The error message indicates that there's an unexpected  element found in the . Here are the relevant details:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed

     D:\Path\To\Your\App\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
AndroidManifest.xml

Here’s the content of my AndroidManifest.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.educational_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="educational_app"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.educational_app.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Other activities should be declared here -->
    </application>
</manifest>

What I’ve Tried
Ensured all <activity> tags are inside the <application> tag.
Checked for duplicate <activity> declarations.
Cleared the build cache using flutter clean.
Validated the XML structure for syntax errors.
Environment
Flutter Version: 3.24.0
Dart Version: 3.5.0
Questions
What could be causing this error?
How can I resolve the unexpected <activity> issue in my manifest?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Entire package name is not necessary in
<activity
            android:name="com.example.educational_app.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

You can just write :
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">

And if you build flutter app then you don't need to set minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion here in AndroidManifest.xml. set it in your android/app/build.gradle file:
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
    }
}

